# Chrome Devtools says there's issues, but the Issues tab is empty?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

In the screenshot above, it indicates that there are 2 issues: 1 orange and 1 blue. However, the Issues tab is empty. These issues have been present on my website for several days, even after restarting Devtools and Chrome. I also disabled the "Enable experimental hide issues menu" experiment.

How can I see these issues?

Comment: I also have this issue.

Comment: Wondered quite some time about this. Still no solution and still no fix for that?

Comment: Experiencing similar. More alarming is that I have danger red colored issues that are not viewable.